# How to hide folder names in a directory?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

I am looking for a way to hide folder names in a Windows 7 library and use only custom icons I setup as indicators. I know there is a hide file names option when I customize the library for videos but it doesn't hide folder names. There is no solution on Google as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

A library is in essence like a foldername, and it behaves exactly the same.

You can't hide foldernames in the sense that a foldername is what makes a folder. It has a property called icon, but a folder is still identified by its foldername.

That said, Windows is somewhat generous when it comes to naming folders.

Although you cannot use a normal space as foldername, you can use other hidden characters as foldernames, such as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> which creates in invisible character.

In order to do this for multiple folders, you will have to use 1 space, 2 spaces, 3 spaces, etc.

Of course, selecting the folder will hilight its name, and there still will be space reserved for its name, so you could as well just use a descriptive name, even if its just a short one.

Comment: Yes I come across invisible character solution but I was hoping for a way without changing folder names just hide them as they are like with the "hide file names" feature.

Comment: Hiding filenames hides the icon too. You can remove libraries all together which in essence does this, but you want the icon to be visible.